# Linux incoming/outgoing packets modifying module

Tags: linux, driver

Can anybody give me a link to manual or sample of linux kernel driver, which can modify  incoming/outgoing packets from/to specified ip-port?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably belongs on serverfault.com, but take a look at `iptables`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kprobes is a way you can do this. Here is a module that uses kprobes with network functions: https://github.com/PanosSakkos/netlog

Comment: is this module can modify packets? I mean data in packets.

Comment: This module just logs, but it has access to the sock structures.